# Extract and flatten JSON in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a JSON column that looks like this:

```
{
    "a": 
    {
        "a0": [], 
        "a1": [], 
        "a2": [1,2,3]
    }, 
    "b": 
    {
        "b1": [], 
        "b2": []
    },
    "b3": []
}
```

I would like to extract `a[a2][1,2,3]` and output them in separate rows:

| value |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Comment: PostgresSQL. I got it to [1,2,3] but I just need to flatten it. "column"::json->'a')::json->'a1'

Comment: You want the json_array_elements function: `select * from json_array_elements('{ "a": { "a0": [], "a1": [], "a2": [1,2,3] }, "b": { "b1": [], "b2": [] }, "b3": [] }'::json)->'a'->'a2');`. Also note you don't need to do `::json` after every `->'key'`.